# script(JS) to login account not working

Tags: javascript

The following code will redirect users to a login pagw:

```
javascript:window.location='https://1.1.1.1/login.html';while(true){if(document.readyState == "complete"){window.onload(document.forms[0].Submit.click());break;}}
```

The script does not work if I paste it into the urlbar (on a blank screen).  It will https://1.1.1.1/login.html but not login.  However, if I go to `https://1.1.1.1/login.html` and paste this script, it works well.

Why does the first solution not work?

Comment: Need 1. where `https://1.1.1.1/login.html` is, or 2. result of things like `console.log(document.forms[0].Submit)`.

Answer (score 1):

window.location='https://1.1.1.1/login.html'

sets the location of the window to an other page. after .window.location the script strops excuting

If you are on the loginpage the URL does not change and in (some) browsers the rest of the script will be excuted